# send x value(number) and y value(number) and other letter value (numbers) to thire textboxes

Tags: vb.net

[image]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
    End Sub

End Class
```

the program will be like this when press open the open file diloge well open the file from the computer and the well show in textbox1 . what I want to do is to send xvalue(the number after(x)) is send to textbox(x) and send yvalue(the number after(y)) is send to textbox(y) and each letter value well send value (number) well send like this and this code is for open the file I think the array must used in this case but I dont know how use the arry

Comment: How is the data stored in the file that you open?

Comment: Look. If we're going to help you, we need to know how the data is stored in the file. If not, this is just going to be another question lying around that a new user has given up on. Please read this - [mcve] If you're not going to persevere with this question. please delete it as it wont be any use to anyone.

Comment: I Apologies i edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, I think the following will work:

```
Dim input As String="N14G73X315.2Y83.7I40.0J6.4A0.0H3K75T11F5M0C0.0"

Dim matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, "\w[0-9.]+")

Dim parts = Matches.Cast(Of System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match).Select(Function(p) New With {.Key=p.Value.Substring(0,1), .Value=p.Value.Substring(1)}).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Key, Function(p) p.Value)

txtX.text = parts("X")
txtY.text = parts("Y")
etc
```

We use a regular expression to split the string into groups of a single letter followed by a number including an optional decimal point. We then use Linq to turn this into a dictionary of numbers (well string representations of numbers) keyed on their corresponding letter from the input. You can then pull these from the dictionary to set each text field

You could also use capture groups on the regular expression instead of splitting the output in the linq statement

Comment: Error 1 Name 'Regex' is not declared.   the program give this error

Comment: Apologies - see the edit, I've now included the full namespace

Comment: Error 1 End of statement expected. now this Error

Comment: Can you be more specific (like where is the error reported)? I've just pasted it and it not only didn't give an error, but also produced the right results

Comment: Here is a link to the code and results running in Linqpad: http://screencast.com/t/qdLmcqwag

Comment: Error 1 Type 'Match' is not defined.

Comment: Match is also defined in System.Text.RegularExpression. I've edited the code to reflect this

Comment: No problem - if you're happy with the answer then please tick it to mark it as the answer

Comment: the code is very good but there is small problem the program cant send the negative value . can you solve this problem please?

Comment: Simple enough - the bing in the square brackets specifies what we'll accept for numbers. Currently it's 0-9 and a decimal point, so we just need to add a minus sign to the list. Since '-' is a special character (used for ranges) we need to escape it, which we do with a '\'. The new regex becomes "\w[\-0-9.]+"